# time data does not match format (match)

Tags: python, datetime

I got the following error:

```
time data '23-MAY-2019 12:49:08' does not match format '%d-%m-%yyyy %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

this is my code:

```
dfbaseline['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfbaseline['Date'], format='%d-%m-%yyyy %H:%M:%S')
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your date *format*.

```
pd.to_datetime(dfbaseline['Date'], format='%d-%m-%yyyy %H:%M:%S')
                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

- `%m` is used to match *Month in  a zero-padded decimal number
  format*(01 to 12).
- `%y` will match year without century as a zero-padded decimal number(00, 01, …, 99)

So you have to change,

- `%b` to match *Month in a locale’s abbreviated name(Jan/Feb/Mar etc)*
- `%Y` to match *Year with century as a decimal number(0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999)*

```
pd.to_datetime(dfbaseline['Date'], format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
                                              ^^^^^
```

See [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes for more information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: thank you, but I still got the same error. ValueError: time data '23-MAY-2019 12:49:08' does not match format '%d-%b-%yyyy %H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: @Nobody My answer is updated. You should also change the year format

Answer (score 0):

You can check out here, Different characters for formatting a DateTime as a string -
[https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=function-formatting-parsing-datetimes-as-strings#:~:text=Characters%20for%20formatting%20a%20dateTime%20as%20a%20string](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=function-formatting-parsing-datetimes-as-strings#:%7E:text=Characters%20for%20formatting%20a%20dateTime%20as%20a%20string)